# Rest Requests returns unexpected end of file from server with Spring WS

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, spring-mvc

I have a problem with my first Spring WS Project. I want to use spring ws to seperate GUI and DAO. Since that didn't work at all, first I wanted to implement the WS in just one project. My problem at the moment is that I get the exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8443/shadowrun/user/Markus2/test":Unexpected end of file from server; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:503)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:452)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:222)
at at.itn.shadowrun.gui.service.client.UserClient.findUser(UserClient.java:26)
```

Here's the part from the *UserClient.java*:

```
@Component("userClient")
public class UserClient extends GenericClient {

@Autowired
public UserClient(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
}

public SUsers findUser(String user, String password) {
    return restTemplate.getForObject(serviceUrl + "user/{user}/{password}", SUsers.class, user, password);
}
// etc
}
```

And finally my *SignInSession.java* which loads the *UserClient.java*:

```
public final class SignInSession extends AuthenticatedWebSession {
@Autowired
private UserClient userClient = new UserClient(new RestTemplate());

@Override
public final boolean authenticate(final String username, final String password) {
currentUser = userClient.findUser(username, password);
// etc
}
}
```

What I think so far:
I find it a bit confusing that I had to write `private UserClient           userClient = new UserClient(new RestTemplate());` to prevent a NullPointerException, but in all tutorials I found it always stated only `@Autowired private UserClient userClient`.

Can anyone give me some guidance and/or maybe some recommended documentation about this? Thank you!

Comment: Sure you don't have to create UserClient yourself, leave that to Spring dependency injection. Get your SignInSession from a Spring application context, don't create it with new, all @Autowired fileds will be autowired or you'll get a Spring error while loading the spring context.

Comment: I tried it like that, but I got a NullPointerException (userClient was NULL).

I think I did something completely wrong with the configuration maybe. For the moment I'm rewriting parts of the application (switched from wicket to spring-mvc) so maybe my problem is gone when I'm finally finished.

But I still don't really understand why the userClient was null

Comment: It was null because you created SignInSession with new, instead of letting Spring create it and do the autowiring. Annotate it with @Component, let spring create it an inject it where you need it.

Comment: I had my configuration done wrong, that's why I got my NullPointer (which I tried to prevent with the new UserClient(new RestTemplate());

Thank you for your help!